# Stats.js getting displayed in other canvas as ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

Doing my first steps with Three.js and wanted to display the Stats.js in an little test-scenario.

https://codepen.io/B33THR333/pen/ExwLbON

I didn't want to use modules for now, but besides that i pretty much used the same code as in the examples:

```
    var stats = new Stats(); 
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    container.appendChild(stats.domElement);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

still the Stats seem to be displayed in a different canvas (whitespace on top) and I don't see where I went wrong here. Has anyone an idea?

Would be really thankful for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending two separate elements to your `container` div. If you want them to overlap so it appears like the stats canvas is part of the renderer, you just need some basic CSS:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}

#container > div {
  position: absolute;  
}
```